# Google Chrome - display download bar at bottom of ALL windows

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I have got Google Chrome on my Mac. When you download something, you get a bar at the bottom with the download progress:

[image: Download Bar]

But when you exit the window and open a new one, the download bar goes away - even though it's still downloading.

How do you make it have the download bar on every window?

Comment: I don't know, but you can press the Mac equivalent of Ctrl+J as a workaround.

Comment: @red it's a poor workaround though, as you can't watch the progress and continue browsing at the same time.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: A large set of Chrome switch options are listed here, but none seem to be do to give you the feature you're after: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No

Based on a search ([here](http://mygooglechrome.blogspot.com.au/2008/09/all-google-chrome-startup-switches.html) and [here](http://lifehacker.com/5045904/the-power-users-guide-to-google-chrome)) on advanced Google Chrome configuration options, it doesn't seem like you can.

Chrome has a limited set of configuration options unlike Firefox.

You will just need to use the shortcuts to bring it back up on new windows <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you open a new tab, then open a page and save it, the downloads bar comes back.  It will only display the current page you saved and any downloads in progress, not ones that finished earlier.

Still it will be displayed, which is a sort of workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple: **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>**

Comment: This opens the Downloads PAGE, not the Downloads BAR at the bottom of the window.